# org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: xml, android-studio, svg, xml-parsing

I have an SVG file, which I import in Android Studio (Android Studio creates an XML file). Even when importing the file in the preview is shown only black. When I run my test program, it crashes.

The crashing code is:

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.chde4);
```

Error:

> org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)

Here a part of the XML-File:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:width="1104dp" android:height="1567dp" android:viewportWidth="1104" android:viewportHeight="1566.43">
  <path android:pathData="M66.05,1205.12l0,2.98 -13.78,0c0,-1.21 0.35,-2.56 1.13,-4.08 0.75,-1.49 2.16,-3.26 4.18,-5.31 2.41,-2.38 3.97,-4.22 4.71,-5.49 0.75,-1.32 1.1,-2.52 1.1,-3.62 0,-1.31 -0.39,-2.37 -1.13,-3.19 -0.75,-0.78 -1.7,-1.2 -2.8,-1.2 -1.17,0 -2.16,0.42 -2.94,1.31 -0.74,0.89 -1.13,2.13 -1.13,3.79l-2.63,-0.35c0.18,-2.41 0.89,-4.26 2.06,-5.5 1.2,-1.2 2.76,-1.84 4.75,-1.84 2.09,0 3.72,0.75 4.81,2.16 1.07,1.42 1.63,3.05 1.63,4.89 0,1.6 -0.42,3.16 -1.27,4.64 -0.89,1.46 -2.48,3.44 -4.89,5.92 -1.52,1.56 -2.48,2.62 -2.94,3.19 -0.46,0.57 -0.82,1.13 -1.1,1.7l10.24,0z" android:fillColor="#2B2A29" android:fillType="nonZero"/>
</vector>
```

I have exported this file from Corel Draw 2018 andalso convertet with Inkscape. Both generate the Error. Even when I convert the SVG to an XML and copy to Android Studio, I get the same Error. What am I doing wrong?